# How to manually add a column while data scraping in UiPath

Tags: uipath

I am scraping an internet shop, and writing down the "name" "price" and "specific good url's" columns. But I also want to add another column with internet shop link (cause I will scrape a lot of them). How can I do that?

Comment: Show the example, not sure what you mean with other column.

Comment: @kwoxer I've decided to use "Add data column" activity, and set it's default value to the link I needed.

Comment: Sounds good with this activity. Didn't it work? Let me know.